# Ionic 4 Admob Integration error : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: (Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzur;)

Tags: compiler-errors, crash, admob, google-play-services, ionic4

I have followed the instructions as per ionic docs but my app crashes on showing ads.
What i have done is as follows:

1. ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-admob-free
2. npm install @ionic-native/admob-free
3. Added the provider in app.module.ts
4. Added the dependency injection in home.page.ts
5. Configure Banner Configurations

Using:

```
const bannerConfig: AdMobFreeBannerConfig = {
      isTesting: true,
      autoShow: true
};
```

and then when trying to show the banner the app is crashing with error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: (Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzur;)
```

My build.gradle is as follows:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        versionCode cdvVersionCode ?: new BigInteger("" + privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("versionCode"))
        applicationId privateHelpers.extractStringFromManifest("package")

        if (cdvMinSdkVersion != null) {
            minSdkVersion cdvMinSdkVersion
        }

        if (cdvMaxSdkVersion != null) {
            maxSdkVersion cdvMaxSdkVersion
        }

        if(cdvTargetSdkVersion != null) {
            targetSdkVersion cdvTargetSdkVersion
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
      abortOnError false;
    }

    compileSdkVersion cdvCompileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion cdvBuildToolsVersion

    // This code exists for Crosswalk and other Native APIs.
    // By default, we multiply the existing version code in the
    // Android Manifest by 10 and add a number for each architecture.
    // If you are not using Crosswalk or SQLite, you can
    // ignore this chunk of code, and your version codes will be respected.

    if (Boolean.valueOf(cdvBuildMultipleApks)) {
        flavorDimensions "default"

        productFlavors {
            armeabi {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 1
                ndk {
                    abiFilters = ["armeabi"]
                }
            }
            armv7 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 2
                ndk {
                    abiFilters = ["armeabi-v7a"]
                }
            }
            arm64 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 3
                ndk {
                    abiFilters = ["arm64-v8a"]
                }
            }
            x86 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 4
                ndk {
                    abiFilters = ["x86"]
                }
            }
            x86_64 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 5
                ndk {
                    abiFilters = ["x86_64"]
                }
            }
        }
    } else if (Boolean.valueOf(cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit)) {
        // This provides compatibility to the default logic for versionCode before cordova-android 5.2.0
        defaultConfig {
            versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    if (cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile) {
        signingConfigs {
            release {
                // These must be set or Gradle will complain (even if they are overridden).
                keyAlias = ""
                keyPassword = "__unset" // And these must be set to non-empty in order to have the signing step added to the task graph.
                storeFile = null
                storePassword = "__unset"
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
        addSigningProps(cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.release)
    }

    if (cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile) {
        addSigningProps(cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.debug)
    }
}

/*
 * WARNING: Cordova Lib and platform scripts do management inside of this code here,
 * if you are adding the dependencies manually, do so outside the comments, otherwise
 * the Cordova tools will overwrite them
 */


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    implementation(project(path: ":CordovaLib"))
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.4"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:27.+"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}
```

Comment: Did you solved it? i'm getting same error! can you help me

Answer (score 1):

I Solve this issue by changing

```
 implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.4"
 implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4"
```

To

```
 implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:+"
 implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+"
```

in `build.gradle(capacitor-cordova-android-plugins)`

Comment: For me it didn't works really well as the "+" refered to the newest version of packages and for me the latest was causing problem so I decided to go with "15.0.1" and no more crash problem for now.